# Change angularjs code to work for jquery pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hi I don't know `angularJS` yet I have a task in that. There is dashboard which is designed in `angularJS`. Now, in that there is link which will
open a pop-up. I have given a task to change that link to another pop-up but that pop-up is in `jQuery`. So, for me it is quite difficult to understand how to 
change this.

I have a xml file where all the label in html are defined. This is the label from where the link is coming.

```
<subcolumn type="a" ngclick="decisioncomp();" styleName="proccheader labe1padding" text="Complete : "  uniqueID="data31" />
```

Now, in the controller file of the same there is a function defined.

```
// complete link click
    $scope.decisioncomp = function () {
        if ($scope.data31 != "") {
            ModalService.showModal({
                templateUrl: "ChartpagePopup/Complete.html",
                controller: "Complete"
            }).then(function (modal) {
                modal.close.then(function (result) {
                    $scope.customResult = "All good!";
                });
            });
        }
        else
            alert($scope.waitingalert);
    };
```

So, I came to know from here the link is going to html and controller. Now, I thought that if changed this  **ModalService.showModal** to not to take controller
or if I send controller empty and replace my html with this html, my work should be done. So what I did is I changed in the Script file for that where this 
funtion is defined.

I commented out line where it says that controller can't be empty.

```
self.showModal = function(options) {
        //  Create a deferred we'll resolve when the modal is ready.
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //  Validate the input parameters.
        var controllerName = options.controller;
        if (!controllerName) {
          //deferred.reject("No controller has been specified.");
          //return deferred.promise;
        }
```

But then the link itself is not opening. I don't know where else to change. I am stuck here. Please someone help me.

Comment: I got something... I have added another function in controller and now the page is coming but it is not coming as a pop. It is rather coming as an webpage. Can anyone help on that